# Django Celery Start

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I'm developing a Django app, using Celery and RabbitMQ as worker. I'm starting Celery with the following command (on Fedora)

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named processe
```

In my office, we are using Ubuntu and are not getting any errors like this.

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py", line 22, in run_from_argv
    ['%s %s' % (argv[0], argv[1])] + argv[2:],
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 901, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 187, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 893, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 868, in execute
    return cls(app=self.app).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 148, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 118, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 220, in run
    return self.target.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 141, in run
    kwargs.get('pool_cls') or self.app.conf.CELERYD_POOL)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/__init__.py", line 26, in get_implementation
    return symbol_by_name(cls, ALIASES)
  File "/home/gurpinars/projects/github/Blog-Env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 80, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named processes
```

Additionally, here is my `pip freeze` output:

```
Django==1.5.2  
PIL==1.1.7  
amqp==1.0.13  
anyjson==0.3.3     
billiard==2.7.3.32  
celery==3.0.23  
django-celery==3.0.23     
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4  
ipdb==0.7  
ipython==1.0.0  
kombu==2.5.14
python-dateutil==2.1
pytz==2013d  
redis==2.8.0  
six==1.4.1   
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide the versions of the various software you are using? A `pip freeze` output would be best, if you are using pip.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specific that you place the output in the question itself to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: I've created a test project using your requirements file and have experienced no problems. What is you OS?

Comment: I removed all virtual env and install again.Now it works but raised another failings: consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.On ubuntu,rabbitmq start automatically but fedora we had to start and restart  manually when changed conf file.